# Rails - remove parameter if ID is hidden?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with some select options that look like the following-

```
<%= select_tag "opt1", options_for_select(OPT.vals,OPT.vals) %>
<%= select_tag "opt2", options_for_select(OPT.vals,OPT.vals) %>
<%= select_tag "opt3", options_for_select(OPT.vals,OPT.vals) %>
```

Elsewhere in the form, the users can decide if they need all 3 of these options, or just 1 or 2. I'm using jQuery .hide and .show as needed to hide or show the select elements, but when I submit the form, rails passes the default value for the hidden elements anyways which makes sense since they still exist, they're just hidden from the user.

How can I stop Rails from passing parameters for hidden elements?

Comment: Rails is mostly irrelevant to the discussion - the question is "how do I stop the browser from passing parameters for hidden elements?"  You can remove the element altogether or perhaps add a hidden field that flags the parameter as hidden (which your server-side code can handle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to add a class to the hidden elements:

```
$('option').hide(500,function(){
    $(this).addClass('toBeRemoved');
});
```

and when you want to show it again:

```
$('option').show(500,function(){
    $(this).removeClass('toBeRemoved');
});
```

and in the end when you want to submit the form:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('.toBeRemoved').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the option {include_blank: true}, the default option will send blank data to the server then.